# Only show buffers that overlap geometry

Tags: qgis, vector, buffer, intersection

I have multiple sites that are surrounded by a buffer. I also have a layer which corresponds to areas affected by changes. I am trying to filter out buffers that are not overlapped by the change geometry.

[image]

As you can see, the green buffer is not overlapped by the change layer, but the orange buffer is.

I want the result to be a layer like this:
[image]

I will be working with possibly hundreds of buffers, so I cannot manually expect each one for overlaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "Select Attributes by location". Put the buffer layer as "Layer to select from" and the Polygon layer as "Additional layer".
Then right-click the buffer layer with selected features and "Save as..."  (make sure you check "Save only selected features") the selected buffers in a new layer.

This, of course, is only feasible if all your buffers are in the same layer.

[image]